# Swing disabled JButtons have no text in Windows LookAndFeel

Tags: java, swing, windows-8.1, look-and-feel

I'm working on a swing gui for my program and recently set the look and feel to the system look and feel. I am working on windows 8.1, so it uses the windows look and feel.

Part of my program is a JList with some Buttons that do stuff on the selected elements of that list. If no element is selected or the list is empty, I want to disable the buttons. 
When using the windows look and feel this leads to them having no text which looks very strange.

**Is there a way to get disabled buttons with the usual greyed-out text while using the windows look and feel?**

Comment: It might be helpful to provide a code samplet showing the problem and your try at it. You might want to consider storing the buttons in a ButtonGroup for group selection checking with the boolean isSelected(). A getter might be needed.

Comment: `Is there a way to get disabled buttons with the usual greyed-out text while using the windows look and feel?` - I have never seen this behaviour. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: JList (logics) by default cant do that, and (graphical artefacts) issue is in your code, by default is possible

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found my mistake.

The behaviour is caused by the buttons being created before setting the look and feel. It can be reproduced with the following code:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Foo extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setVisible(true);
    }

    JButton jButton = new JButton("toggle enable");
    JButton jButton2 = new JButton("text");

    public Foo() {

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
                | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        add(jButton);

        add(jButton2);

        jButton.addActionListener(event -> jButton2.setEnabled(!jButton2.isEnabled()));

        pack();
    }

}
```

For my particular case I fixed it by setting the look and feel in my main method instead of the window constructor.